# Pandas drop excluding more than the passed index

Tags: python, pandas

I have this snippets code:

```
for cust_ids in batch(deal.customer_id.unique(), 50):
   filters = deal.loc[deal.customer_id.isin(cust_ids)]
   deal.drop(filters.index, inplace=True)
```

in the first loop, the deal dataframe shape is (7436, 28) and the filters shape is (53, 28).
But in the second loop, after I drop the 53 rows the deal dataframe go to shape (6294, 28), why?

the batch function only breaks a bigger array into smallers:

```
def batch(iterable, n=1):
    l = len(iterable)
    for ndx in range(0, l, n):
        yield iterable[ndx:min(ndx + n, l)]
```

edit:
this is a logic bug in my code. Please ignore this question

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with a dataframe of my own:
`import pandas as pd; import numpy as np`
`deal = pd.DataFrame({"customer_id": np.random.randint(10000, 11000, 10000), "col_1": np.random.random(10000), "col_2": np.random.random(10000)})`

I added `print(deal.shape)` and `print(filters.shape)` to the function and found nothing unusual.

Can you provide some sample data that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to drop rows while you loop over your dataframe.

Try this version

```
filters = deal[deal['customer_id'].isin(cust_ids)]
deal.drop(filters.index, inplace=True)
```

Or this shortcut:

```
deal = deal[~deal['customer_id'].isin(cust_ids)]
```